# Swapping the values of elements in the array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

I recently learnt pointers and began trying simple operations and simple functions with it and I did a swapping function that swaps first value and last value of elements in the array using pointers.
Now my question is, while I have two pointers, a pointer basically points to a memory location of another variable correct? So I assigned the two pointers to last and first values of an array and I printed the values and they have swapped. But when I printed the Array the first values and last values, have also swapped. Which is what I do not understand, I only printed the array and didn't include pointers in the printing process.

Here is my code, and would appreciate if someone could explain why the array also swapped its values.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


void swap(int* swapptr, int arr[], int* swapptr2, int size);

int main() {
int size;
int  arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
int* swap1, * swap2;
size = 6;
swap1 = arr;
swap2 = &arr[size-1];
cout << "The value of the first element is " << *swap1 << " and second element is " << *swap2 << " \n 
\n";

swap(swap1, arr, swap2, size);

cout << "After swap the value of first is " << *swap1 << " and second is " << *swap2 << "\n \n ";
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

}




void swap(int* swapptr, int arr[], int*swapptr2, int size) {
int temp = arr[0];
swapptr = arr;
*swapptr2 = arr[size-1];
*swapptr = *swapptr2;
*swapptr2 = temp;


}
```

Comment: swapptr and arr are the same in swap

Comment: Hard to know what you're not understanding here. If I've understood your question you're saying that you made two pointers point to the first and last elements of an array, used those pointers to swap two values, and then you're surprised that the array values swapped? What else where you expecting to happen? The pointers are pointing at the array, so if you change the values the pointers are pointing at, then the array changes. That's how pointers work.

Comment: @john My apologies Sir, I just began learning pointers and would like to understand them more.

Comment: Incidentally your swap function is a bit strange, it seems like a cross between a pointer swap function, and a function to swap elements of an array. I think it's clear you still have some confusion around pointers (which would not be unusual).

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar That's fine, but I'm not sure what it is that you don't understand. Why are you surprised that the array values swapped? Can you explain what your thinking is?

Comment: @john Sir, as I mentioned earlier I was trying new things. So I just wanted to assign a pointer to the first value of an array and another point to the last value and swap these both. While doing so, since I am using pointers I have also swapped the values of the array itself as well.

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar So you are trying to swap the pointers, not swap the array? In that case you need to use pointers to pointers.

Comment: Yes Sir, I have understood now, before this function I had a function for swapping pointers but I just wanted to try it on an array. Thank you

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar You can a pointer in a function to change **what the pointer is pointing at**, you cannot change the pointer itself. This is an incredibly common misunderstanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213484/discussion-between-johnny-joestar-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you are de-referencing the pointer in the swapping function, you are accessing the values stored in the variables the pointers are pointing to

So any change in the pointer's 'values' is reflected in the variables to which they are pointing to.

Comment: Sir, I know what a call-by-reference is and actually reviewed my code before I asked to see if I am having call-by-references anywhere but I don't seem to find any.